# How stop Eclipse to auto install plugins?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I've installed Eclipse Neon Java EE. When I uninstall some plugins and restart Eclipse for apply changes, the eclipse updater reinstall all the plugins I have uninstalled. How do I uninstall software without Eclipse reinstalling it?

Comment: Did you check this http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-p2-autoupdate.htm

Comment: @saurav yes, I have deactivated this config but it should notify me when updates are available, instead, it automatically downloads everything I've just uninstalled before the Eclipse retarts to "apply modifications".